# Is it required to capitalize the initials of a phrase that is used as an alternative to 'the Earth', 'the Moon', etc?

Tags: capitalization

I'd like to know if it is correct to refer to the Earth as *the green planet*, or it should be written as *The Green Planet*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Earth is capitalised because it's a name (a proper noun).

The green planet is not a name, so shouldn't be capitalised.